# .onDrop not working in views within a Form and Section in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, drop

My  drop  delegate  doesn't get called when attached to view that is inside Form/Section. See code below.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var text = "Goodbye"  {
    didSet  {
      print(text)
    }
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    Form {
      Section  {
        Text(text)
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
          .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
          .onDrop(of: ["text"], delegate: MyDropDelegate(text: $text))
      }
    }
  }
}

struct MyDropDelegate: DropDelegate {
  @Binding var text: String
  
  func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
    self.text = "Received drop text"
    return true
  }
}
```

Comment out the Form/Section and it works fine.

What is the problem?

Comment: Works fine here, Xcode 13 / iOS 15.

Comment: OK... I'm using Xcode 12.5 / 14. Updating to Xcode 13 / 15 later this month and  probably Monterey also.

Comment: Confirmed that  it works on Xcode 13 / iOS 15.